# Looking to write Simple Cash Register App, In over my head?

Tags: java

My parents own a little pizza place, and they have been wanting to switch over to an electronic cash register with touch screen and a small printer for reciepts.

They had one installed while I was away and I just saw it today. The one that they got is way too complicated for their needs. They are a small take out and delivery place but the software which they were given was made for a restuarant with tables and servers.

I thought that I could write them an app in java (I'm a third year Comp-Sci student) to do what they needed.

I'm wondering if I should attempt this or it is too much of a complicated task. What I think that it would need to have, is there products (sizes of pizzas/toppings/slices of pizza etc.) added in. It would also need to be able to print out reciepts for orders to a small printer, and open/close the cash till.

EDIT: Also the things I am most scared about is handling the connection to a printer/cash till. Is this a hard thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts on this, as a Java developer:

- The app logic

  - Dead simple, anyone could do that with some basic Java knowledge. If you expect this to present exact totals, you will also need to know some things about taxes.
- The UI

  - Java doesn't make this especially easy on it's own (I personally think Swing is one of the most god-awful libraries ever made), but it's not that hard to make a simple UI.
- Making it interface with external devices

  - If your vendor provides documentation, then you could possibly figure out how to load a driver with JNI and send commands. However, I doubt your courses have taught you about that, it's a pretty specific task. If your vendor doesn't provide documentation on the driver, you are going to spend a long, loooong time trying to reverse engineer it.

I'm all for learning by doing though. As a college student, my time was essentially worthless unless you count WoW characters as some kind of bizarre currency, and spending it on something like this would definitely have been better than clearing Hyjal for the 30th time.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm worried about! Communicating with the printer/Till :( Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No problem. Just check to see what kind of support your vendor provides *first*. You might be happily surprised, and it shouldn't take more than a half hour of reading/phone calls to figure that out. If you can count on support from them, then this gets exceptionally easy as writing to a printer is just like writing to any output stream (like System.out).

Comment: Also, remember to accept your answers!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why this wouldn't be doable!

If i were in your position i would ask for a refund from the original software company and write a web-application that also allows orders to be made via the internet. With an education in comp-sci you shouldn't have any problems with that, also its a good opportunity to sharpen your swords.

Just make sure that the (pdf) Invoices you create are in line with Tax regulations in your State!

Then use the money your parents paid for the software for a family vacation.

I wish you alot of fun, both writing the app and on your vacation! :)

Comment: thanks, that makes me want to go for it more :)

Comment: about the printer... If it isn't a problem that your parents need to press Ctrl+P and enter to print the invoice, why not try if you can interface your printer via the browser?